# Query Google Calendar events based on custom tags

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script setup in Google Apps Script that creates Calendar events and includes a tag with a unique identifier. I have another script that needs to do a search for existing events and deletes them. Is there a way where I can specifically search for events with only that tag and value? In the documentation I see you can include a search string but this does not seem to find the event based on the unique key.

I understand the alternative is to do a broad search, loop through found events and delete where that tag is that value, but this seems really inefficient. Am I missing something here?

-edit some example code-

```
eventSeries = cal.createEventSeries(name, startTime, endTime, CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().times(6), {
    description: descriptionText
});

eventSeries.setTag('uniqueID', id)
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? About `Google Apps Script that creates Calendar events and includes a tag with a unique identifier`, you have an object including `a unique identifier` as the key? I couldn't image your situation from your question.

Comment: Yeah so when you create an Event or EventSeries you can add a tag with a key/value pair like so

     var eventSeries = cal.createEventSeries(name, startTime, endTime, CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().times(6), {
         description: descriptionText
     });
eventSeries.setTag('uniqueID', id)

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your additional information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the calendar event with the specific tag using Google Apps Script.

For this, as a sample, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

When you want to retrieve the event with the key and value of `uniqueID` and `sample`, I would like to propose the following sample script.

```
var id = "sample";
var res = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime).filter(e => e.getTag('uniqueID') == id);
if (res.length > 0) {  // or res.length == 1
  var event = res[0];  // This is the searched event.
  
  // do something
  
}
```

- Please set `startTime, endTime` for searching events.

#### Reference:

- [getTag(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#gettagkey)

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Is there any documentation around that filter method? I can't seem to find it anywhere. 

I will try your solution later today and mark the answer as correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Arthur Noort Thank you for replying. About `filter`, this is the method of Javascript. In this case, you can see the document at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Ah I see, I thought it was a method of the Event class. So it's still doing a broad search and then filtering. Do you know if that has performance issues if the time period is quite long and there are many other events?

Comment: @Arthur Noort Thank you for replying. In the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for directly searching the specific event using the specific tag. So I thought that above sample might be suitable as the current method. And about the process cost of `filter`, it is high with and without V8. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6 and https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3331e1e631d619abef8f32c4be14ba3a